# Find in a list if there are elements present in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have this list of numbers:

```
"123"
"321"
"435"
"128"
```

And I have a hashMap with these values:

```
"User 1" -> 700
"User 2" -> 123
"User 3" -> 321
```

I want to get the elements from my list that has the same key value in the HashMap.
I other words, with this example I want to get from my list these elements:

```
"123"
"321"
```

Because these are the elements that are present in my HashMap. So far this is my try, but I am getting false for all of this:

```
      getPhoneInformation().stream().forEach(phoneNumber -> {
            phoneNumber.stream().forEach(phone -> {
                assignedToMap.keySet().toString());
                if(phone.getPhoneNumber().contains(assignedToMap.keySet().stream().toString())) {
                    System.out.println("SAME_NUMBER");
                    
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Are the hashmap's numbers unique? If so, why not create a new hashmap with swapped key and values (both as strings)? Then you could walk your list and use `containsKey()`.

Comment: What is the return type of `getPhoneInformation()` ? What is the type of `phoneNumber` ? Sorry, but this is frankly pointless `assignedToMap.keySet().stream().toString()` - you're turning a stream into a string which will result in a sequence of random symbols. And you might want to do something more useful apart from printing "same_number" like storing the result somehow, if so it is also worth to specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
public static void solution() {
    // just your sample data
    final List<String> numberList = List.of(
            "123",
            "321",
            "435",
            "128"
    );

    final Map<String, Integer> theMap = Map.ofEntries(
            Map.entry("User 1", 700),
            Map.entry("User 2", 123),
            Map.entry("User 3", 321)
    );

    // here comes the magic
    List<String> result = numberList.stream()
            .filter(num -> theMap.containsValue(Integer.parseInt(num)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // dump the results to STDOUT
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

I'm gonna skip any explanation since the "magic" is actually one line of code and I hope pretty self-explanatory, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this, here's one.

First, let's start with your sample data:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(123, 321, 435, 128);

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("User 1", 700);
map.put("User 2", 123);
map.put("User 3", 321);
```

With that setup, this code would do what you're looking for:

```
1. Collection<Integer> numbersInMap = map.values();
2. List<Integer> numbersInBoth = new ArrayList<>();
3. for (Integer number : numbers) {
4.     if (numbersInMap.contains(number)) {
5.         numbersInBoth.add(number);
6.     }
7. }
8. System.out.println(numbersInBoth);
```

A few points:

- line 1: As a first step, get all of the numbers in the map – 700, 123, 321 – by asking the map for all the values it contains by calling [`values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#values()):
- line 2: create an empty list that you can use to gather your results; each time you find a number that's in both the map and the list, add it to `numbersInBoth`
- line 3: iterate over each number in the `numbers` list. As an alternative, you could also iterate over each number in `numberInMap` collection, and then adjust the loop body accordingly (look for matches in the list instead of the map).
- line 4: check if the number from "list" is also in the "map" numbers
- line 5: if in both, add it to `numbersInBoth`
- line 8: print out `numbersInBoth`, this is the overlapping set of results

Running that code produces this output:

```
[123, 321]
```

If you want to use streams, replace lines 2-7 with this:

```
List<Integer> numbersInBoth = numbers.stream()
        .filter(numbersInMap::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: <del>I don't want to be picky @Kaan, but your added idea looks familiar ;-)</del> Sorry, that's still on the `numbersInMap` collection. My bad.

Comment: Oh, did you also run "replace with collect" on the `for` loop in IntelliJ? I did, too. ;-)

Comment: Nah, it's Netbeans :-D.

Comment: `List<Integer> numbersInBoth = new ArrayList<>(numbers); numbersInBoth.retainAll(map.values());`

Answer (score 0):

Minimal and easily reproducible answer:

**Mutable list**:

Just use `removeIf` to get rid of the items found among the map's values using `containsValue`).

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of("123", "321", "435", "128"));

Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of(
    "User 1", 700,
    "User 2", 123,
    "User 3", 321);

list.removeIf(string -> !map.containsValue(Integer.parseInt(string)));

System.out.println(list);
```

> ```
> [123, 321]
> ```

**Immutable list**:

Use the very same condition, but negated in the `Stream#filter` as now you want to *keep* such values (not remove).

```java
List<String> list = List.of("123", "321", "435", "128");

Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of(
    "User 1", 700,
    "User 2", 123,
    "User 3", 321);


List<String> filteredList = list.stream()
        .filter(string -> map.containsValue(Integer.parseInt(string)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(filteredList);
```

> ```
> [123, 321]
> ```

---

**Few notes below the line**:

1. I find using `Set` instead of `List` more appropriate as you don't want duplicated values.
2. Aim for the data type consistency and avoid string-to-integer comparison: Perhaps `List<Integer>`/`Set<Integer>` would be more suitable.